# Finder: Error changing file association

Tags: finder

When trying to change the associated application that opens when double clicking a file, I'm seeing the error message:

**You can’t change the item *"<filename>"* to always open in the selected application.**
The item is either locked or damaged, or in a folder you don’t have permission to modify (error code -54).

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Is this one specific file, all files in a certain folder, or of a certain type, or all files on a drive, or the entire system, could you give more detail about how widespread the issue is.

Comment: @unknowndomain it was one particular file I wanted to change the association of, but it did affect all files in that particular location.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this issue was the file I was attempting to change was a remote server, mounted via [`sshfs`](https://github.com/osxfuse/sshfs).

If I copy the file I'd like to change the association with to my desktop and try again, it worked successfully and files on the remote server correctly open in the desired application.